# How can I use all four weapon slots?

Tags: far-cry-3

How do you use your four weapon slots in *Far Cry 3*? I own the holster/sling for four guns but I can only use two even though I own more.

Comment: Do you mean the "Heavy Duty Holster"? For which you need 2 Shark Skins

Comment: should attempt to reword this question, kinda confusing.

Comment: When you press and hold `1` do all four weapons slots show up _without_ a padlock icon?

Comment: For what? PC ? Xbox 360? PS3?  Controls will be different for each [ though similar ]

Comment: press and hold LB then use the right analog stick to choose a weapon.

Answer (score 3):

Go to a shop, and then go to the weapon you have (or want to buy), and then select the 'Equip' menu:
[image]

Then, assign that weapon to a slot:
[image]

You should now be able to switch between all four weapons, assuming you have assigned weapons to all four slots and have the [Heavy Duty Holster](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Crafting#Weapon_Holsters) (four weapon slots).

Comment: To the downvoter(s): Could you please comment on why you downvoted this answer? This is so I (and others) would know what was wrong with it, and so I could address that concern or edit the answer to improve it. When downvotes are left without comments and the reasons for doing so are unclear, you'll often see users (like myself) wanting to know the reason why.

Comment: your answer is more than satisfying @galacticninja

Answer (score -2):

I think you can only quick switch between two weapons, even while holding 4 total.

Comment: Not the case for PC, keys 1 through 4 will equip the weapons you have.

Comment: nope, you can press key 1 through 4 to switch weapon in PC, as @kotekzot mentioned above, the sequence is from the twelve o'clock as key 1 weapon, and 2-3-4 as clockwise sequence.